# Compile See5 / C50 GPL Edition

Tags: decision-trees

See5 / C5.0 is Data Mining Tools available from [rulequest](https://www.rulequest.com/see5-info.html)

I want to compile C50 for Linux, preferably for CentOS 6.x, but I am unable to compile. I have also tried on Ubuntu, but not success there as well.

I have downloaded C50.tgz from [C5.0 Release 2.07 GPL Edition](https://www.rulequest.com/GPL/C50.tgz)
After extracting when I run ./Makefile it gives below error on Ubuntu18

```
./Makefile: line 9: CC: command not found
./Makefile: line 10: CFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 11: S: command not found
./Makefile: line 11: LFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 12: SHELL: command not found
./Makefile: line 19: src: command not found
./Makefile: line 48: obj: command not found
./Makefile: line 59: all:: command not found
cat defns.i global.c c50.c construct.c formtree.c info.c discr.c contin.c subset.c prune.c p-thresh.c trees.c siftrules.c ruletree.c rules.c getdata.c implicitatt.c mcost.c confmat.c sort.c update.c attwinnow.c classify.c formrules.c getnames.c modelfiles.c utility.c xval.c\
        | egrep -v 'defns.i|extern.i' >c50gt.c
make: /bin/csh: Command not found
Makefile:75: recipe for target 'c5.0' failed
make: *** [c5.0] Error 127
./Makefile: line 61: CC: command not found
./Makefile: line 61: LFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 61: -o: command not found
./Makefile: line 67: obj: command not found
./Makefile: line 67: c5.0dbg:: command not found
./Makefile: line 68: CC: command not found
./Makefile: line 68: obj: command not found
./Makefile: line 68: -g: command not found
./Makefile: line 74: src: command not found
./Makefile: line 74: c5.0:: command not found
./Makefile: line 75: src: command not found
./Makefile: line 77: CC: command not found
./Makefile: line 77: LFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 77: -O3: command not found
strip: 'c5.0': No such file
./Makefile: line 82: obj: command not found
./Makefile: line 85: .c.o:: command not found
./Makefile: line 86: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./Makefile: line 86: `  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<'
```

If I run make command, it gives below error.

```
make c5.0 
make: /bin/csh: Command not found Makefile:60: recipe for
target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 127
```

gcc version is:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I have to write an answer... what happens when you just give the command ```make``` without target?

Comment: Error of make command without target is also same as the error or make c5.0.
By the way I have fixed the issue. I will be adding the solution shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extracting `C50.tgz` file, give execution rights to `Makefile`.

```
chmod +x Makefile
```

Then install csh

```
sudo apt install csh
```

Run below command to check if csh is install and check csh version (if installed)

```
dpkg -l csh
```

It should show output like below.

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                           Version              Architecture         Description
+++-==============================-====================-====================-==================================================================
ii  csh                            20110502-3           amd64                Shell with C-like syntax
```

Now run below command.

```
./Makefile
```

It should give output like below. (Ignore the warning messages).

```
./Makefile: line 9: CC: command not found
./Makefile: line 10: CFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 11: S: command not found
./Makefile: line 11: LFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 12: SHELL: command not found
./Makefile: line 19: src: command not found
./Makefile: line 48: obj: command not found
./Makefile: line 59: all:: command not found
cat defns.i global.c c50.c construct.c formtree.c info.c discr.c contin.c subset.c prune.c p-thresh.c trees.c siftrules.c ruletree.c rules.c g     etdata.c implicitatt.c mcost.c confmat.c sort.c update.c attwinnow.c classify.c formrules.c getnames.c modelfiles.c utility.c xval.c\
        | egrep -v 'defns.i|extern.i' >c50gt.c
gcc -ffloat-store  -O3 -o c5.0 c50gt.c -lm
c50gt.c: In function ‘ListAttsUsed’:
c50gt.c:14025:12: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
      Att = (Attribute) DefSVal(D[e]);
            ^
c50gt.c: In function ‘Error’:
c50gt.c:15561:17: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
     fprintf(Of, Buffer);
                 ^~~~~~
strip c5.0
rm c50gt.c
./Makefile: line 61: CC: command not found
./Makefile: line 61: LFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 61: -o: command not found
./Makefile: line 67: obj: command not found
./Makefile: line 67: c5.0dbg:: command not found
./Makefile: line 68: CC: command not found
./Makefile: line 68: obj: command not found
./Makefile: line 68: -g: command not found
./Makefile: line 74: src: command not found
./Makefile: line 74: c5.0:: command not found
./Makefile: line 75: src: command not found
./Makefile: line 77: CC: command not found
./Makefile: line 77: LFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 77: -O3: command not found
./Makefile: line 82: obj: command not found
./Makefile: line 85: .c.o:: command not found
./Makefile: line 86: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./Makefile: line 86: `  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<'
```

You will see a new file `c5.0*`
Check command line options with below command.

```
./c5.0 -h
```

it should show below output.

```
C5.0 [Release 2.07 GPL Edition]         Fri Mar 15 17:43:39 2019
-------------------------------

    Options:
        -f <filestem>   application filestem
        -r              use rule-based classifiers
        -u <bands>      order rules by utility in bands
        -w              invoke attribute winnowing
        -b              invoke boosting
        -t <trials>     number of boosting trials
        -p              use soft thresholds
        -e              focus on errors (ignore costs file)
        -s              find subset tests for discrete atts
        -g              do not use global tree pruning
        -m <cases>      restrict allowable splits
        -c <percent>    confidence level (CF) for pruning
        -S <percent>    training sample percentage
        -X <folds>      cross-validate
        -I <integer>    random seed for sampling and cross-validation
        -h              print this message
```

Now C50 is ready to be used. Here is a sample command(assuming sampledata.data and sampledata.names files exists in the same folder).

```
./c5.0 -r -f sampledata
```

After successful execution of the command, sampledata.rules will be generated in the same folder.

See full tutorial from [here](https://www.rulequest.com/see5-unix.html)